# Not able to connect to wifi, using wl driver, having already blacklisted bcma and brcmsmac (BCM4313)

Tags: 12.04, wireless, networking, drivers, broadcom

I have the broadcom 4313 [14e4:4727] wireless interface and my laptop is Lenovo z580 running Ubuntu 12.04.

The output of `lspci -k | grep wl`, gives

```
Kernel driver in use: wl  
 Kernel modules: wl, bcma, brcmsmac
```

I have blacklisted bcma and brcmsmac in `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf`

and under `/etc/modules`, I have added `wl`.

`wl` used to work fine originally, but after an update, `brmcsmac` got pushed to my system.

Since that I have been trying everything possible to get my wifi working, to no avail. I have tried disabling `wl` and using `brcsmac`, but that does not help as well.

If anybody has an idea to fix this, kindly suggest.

Answer (score 0):

My acer netbook has the 4727 broadcom adapter as well, and caused me problems in 12.04.

What worked for me has installing 3.6 backports using synaptic.  I found something in my app docs folder with the following:

linux-backports-modules-cw-3.6-precise-generic

which is, I think, the name of the package.

I'm not 100% on that because I'm running 13.04 on it now.  Which, BTW, hasn't given me anywhere near as many wireless problems.  It worked acceptably at install and since installing bcmwl-kernel-source (which is the same driver as "additional drivers" installs but synaptic is more reliable) it's worked perfectly.  Just a thought.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I'll give this a shot and let you know how it goes. If it doesn't work, I think I'll switch to 13.04 too. I've spent way too much time trying to get wifi to work on 12.04.